# Solo puedo subrayar la letra o y no toda la palabra

Tags: python-3.x

Cuando pongo underline = True, solo me subraya la letra o y no me subraya toda la palabra de la variable, ya lo intente poner en tkinter.Label(), pero no me funciona y solo subraya la letra o. Aquí dejo el código:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import tkinter

principal = tkinter.Tk()

texto = tkinter.Label(principal, text = "Hola Mundo")

texto.configure(underline=True, font=("Calibri", 24, "italic"))

texto.pack()

principal.mainloop()
```

Y aquí dejo como me sale al correr el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

La forma más fácil es pasarle el argumento a la fuente para que lo aplique a todo el texto

```
import tkinter

principal = tkinter.Tk()

texto = tkinter.Label(principal, text = "Hola Mundo")
texto.configure(font=('Calibri 24 italic underline'))
texto.pack()

principal.mainloop()
```

Esto devuelve:

[image: Hola Mundo]